# Хочу оптимизировать код JavaScript, но не знаю как это лучше сделать

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

```js
window.onload = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML += '<div class="block"></div>';
  }

  var turn = 0;

  document.getElementById('game').onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target.className == 'block') {
      if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        event.target.innerHTML = 'x';
      } else {
        event.target.innerHTML = 'o';
      }

      turn++;
      checkWinner();
    }
  }

  function checkWinner() {
    var allBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

    //Проверка для x по первой строке
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[1].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //Проверка для x по второй строке
    if (allBlock[3].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[5].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //Проверка для x по третьей строке 
    if (allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[7].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //По первой вертикали слева
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[3].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //По второй вертикали
    if (allBlock[1].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[7].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //По третьей вертикали 
    if (allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[5].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //По диагонали
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');
    if (allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'x') alert('first gamer winner!');

    //second gamer win

    //Проверка для 0 по первой строке
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[1].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //Проверка для o по второй строке
    if (allBlock[3].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[5].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //Проверка для o по третьей строке 
    if (allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[7].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //По первой вертикали слева
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[3].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //По второй вертикали
    if (allBlock[1].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[7].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //По третьей вертикали 
    if (allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[5].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');

    //По диагонали
    if (allBlock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[8].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');
    if (allBlock[2].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allBlock[6].innerHTML == 'o') alert('second gamer winner!');
  }

}
```

```css
#game {
  width: 100px;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>
<button onClick='document.location.reload();'>New game?</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел ввиду оптимизировать кусочек кода, в котором происходят проверки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function checkWinFor(symbol, els) {
  var wins = [
    [0, 1, 2], // horizontal
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6], // vertical
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8], // diagonal
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
    var match = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < wins[i].length; j++) {
      if (els[wins[i][j]].innerHTML != symbol) {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function checkWinner() {
  var gamers = [
    { symbol: 'x', message: 'first gamer winner!' },
    { symbol: 'o', message: 'second gamer winner!' }
  ];

  var allBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
  for (var i = 0; i < gamers.length; i++) {
    if (checkWinFor(gamers[i].symbol, allBlock)) {
      alert(gamers[i].message);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```